# Hamburger menu click animation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

The issue is that for example when I am in the mobile window mode and i click on the burger and right after without closing the burger zoom out to larger resolution and zoom back to mobile size again and click on the burger is shows me like its activated but it actually doesn't activate the burger menu slide down.

Here you can see the example!
http://jsfiddle.net/3n0zL27x/1/
Help will be very much appreciated!!

```
  /// create a list and append to mobilemenu
var $select = $("<ul></ul>");

$("#mobileMenu").append($select);

////  Get each element in the menu li

$( "#menu li" ).each(function(){
//SELECTING ELEMENT RELATED TO THE FUNCTION
    var $anchor = $(this);
    // SELECTING THE LIST IN FUTURE THE MENU
var $li = $("<li></li>"); 
    // ADDING TEXT FROM EACH ANCHOR TO THE LIST
  $li.text($anchor.text());
    /// ADDing the list item to the unorderd list
    $select.append($li);
});


var isclicked = false;
// USER CLICKING ON THE BURGER AND ACTIVATEING THE MENU
$(".burger").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
$(this).toggleClass('active');
/// IF THE BURGER MENU IS CLICKED FADE OUT THE LIST ITEMS AND SCROLL UP THE BACKGROUND
if (isclicked === true) {   
$("#menu").animate({
    height: "80px",
  }, 1500 );
    $("#mobileMenu li").fadeOut(1000);

isclicked = false;       
}
/// IF THE BURGER MENU IS NOT CLICKED SLIDE DOWN THE BACKGROUND AND FADE IN THE LIST ITEMS    
else {

$("#menu").animate({
    height: "150px",
  }, 1500 );
$("#mobileMenu li").css({
      padding: "5px 0px",
    color: "white"
    });    
$("#mobileMenu li").fadeIn(3500 );  
isclicked = true;
/// IF USER RESIZES THE PAGE REMOVE THE MENU
    $( window ).resize(function() {
    $("#mobileMenu li").css({
      display: "none",
    });

    $("#menu").css({
      height: "80px",
    });
        // SET BURGER STATE TO NOT ACTIVATED
    $(".burger").removeClass('active');
});       
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also set isclicked to false in the resize event handler:

```
 /// IF USER RESIZES THE PAGE REMOVE THE MENU
$( window ).resize(function() {
    $("#mobileMenu li").css({
      display: "none",
    });

    $("#menu").css({
      height: "80px",
    });
    // SET BURGER STATE TO NOT ACTIVATED
    $(".burger").removeClass('active');
    isclicked = false;       
 });       
}});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/wsco284h/)